# Plone 4.2 TinyMCE jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: tinymce, plone

I am currently writing a replacement for the plone dialog infrastructure. Mostly for personal use and fun, but available on github as collective.js.jqueryuidialog.

Currently I'm struggling to manage the initialization for the tinyMCE editor in the dialogs.

I tried to get the missing scripts with getScript, but then I get stuck. I googled and found some init hooks, like this one

```
$(document).bind('loadInsideOverlay', function() {
    $('textarea.mce_editable').each(function() {
        var config = new TinyMCEConfig($(this).attr('id'));
        config.init();
    });
});
```

but none worked.

Any ideas or recommendations to read further?

**Update**

I updated `Products.TinyMCE` to version 1.3.3 and proceeded through the upgrade steps in the ZMI. All other functionality is still working (Yeehaa).

I realized, that the call seems to have changed, since all pages with a tinyMCE on it, now issue a `get` command to a view named `tiny_mce_gzp.js` that seems to deliver the actual configured editor from the portal.

Actually I am digging the source to find that call and copy it's behavior.